# For what values ​of $d\in \mathbb{R}$ the set $d\mathbb{S}^{1}$ is a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations

We denote the set by $d\mathbb{S}^{1}=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2| a^2+b^2=d^2\}$

Let $H$ be a nonempty subset of a vector space $V$. We say that $H$ is a vector subspace of $V$ if it satisfies the following

i) $\forall x,y\in H$ you have to $x+y\in H$

ii) $\forall x \in H$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ you have to $\alpha x\in H$.

Using this, to prove that the set dS1 is a vector subspace, the following must be true:

Let $(x,y), (w,z)\in d\mathbb{S}^1$ I must prove that $(x+w,y+z)\in d\mathbb{S}^1$.

I mean I have to prove that $(x+w)^2+(y+z)^2=d^2$

And $(\alpha x)^2+(\alpha y)^2=d^2$ $  \forall (x,y)\in d\mathbb{S}^1$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

Doing calculations I get that $(x+w)^2+(y+z)^2=2d^2+2xw+2yz$ and $(\alpha x)^2+(\alpha y)^2=\alpha^2d^2$

But it doesn't help me much to find values ​​for $d$.

I thought to do it for cases $d=0$, $d>0$ and $d<0$.

If we take $d = 0$ we have that $0\mathbb{S}^1=\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2| a^2+b^2=0\}=\{0\}$ Which is clearly a vector subspace.

But for the other cases it is confusing to me. Any suggestion?

Comment: For some subset of a vector space to be a subspace it **must** contain the zero vector. Why won't you begin from here?

Comment: @DonAntonio If so, the set $d\mathbb{S}^1$ contains the zero vector provided that $d = 0$

Comment: @DonAntonio I think I understand. For a nonempty subset to be a vector subspace it must contain the zero vector. If so, for $ d <0 $ and $ d> 0 $ the set $d\mathbb{S}^1$ will not contain the zero vector, so the only possibility is $d = 0$. Right?

Comment: To see what the values of $d$ might be, think geometrically. What does this set look like for various $d$? Do you know what a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ looks like geometrically?

Comment: @GP_1729 Well, there you go: it **must** be $\;d=0\;$ ...so what the set $\;d\Bbb S^!\;$ is?

Comment: @GP_1729 actually we require that vector spaces themselves must always be nonempty, so it is not just that a nonempty subset needs to contain the zero vector to be a subspace, but that a subset must be nonempty, closed under addition, and closed under scalar multiplication to be a subspace.